# What's the meaning of the joint feature function in structured prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, perceptron

When describing the algorithm of [`structured perceptron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_prediction#Structured_perceptron) (it's used in `structured SVM` as well), the inference rule used is:

```
y_hat = argmax_y (w * fee(x,y) )
```

What is the meaning of this joint feature function `fee(x,y)`? Sometimes it's expressed as: `fee(x,y) = 0.5*y*x` - why?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_prediction  describes it as `Φ(x, y)` that maps a training sample `x` and a candidate prediction `y` to a vector of length `n(x and y)` ... think of it as s glorified hypothesis function, and similarly what it is will vary based on the problem you're trying to solve. See also: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_support_vector_machine

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyStrings... sorry but I didn't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate on it? What is the meaning of "to map x and y to a vector etc."? And could you please answer my question on the meaning of using 0.5*y*x for structured SVM? Thanks.

Comment: I think the jump from regular perceptron to multiclass is explained nicely here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron ... they also discuss the "feature vector" in plsin English here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_vector. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JohnnyStrings - OK, I read through the links you provided... I think I can now ask my questions a bit more clearly: **1.** assuming that I understand what f(x) is, what is f(x,y)? **2.** In the multiclass perceptron example in your link, they use f(x,y) = x*y. What is the meaning of multiplying the vector x with y - when y is essentially any real number? Thanks again...

Comment: Some good discussion here: https://pystruct.github.io/intro.html ... but I don't know specifically why they chose 0.5x*y, sorry.